# Running a for loop on data from Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to dynamically show photos on my moms wedding website that she adds to her photos albums on Facebook but I am having trouble getting the images to render and loop. My get request is working and currently pulling in the image link and the id of each photo in the album. This is an example of the json that is returned.

```
{
 "photos": {
  "data": [
     {
        "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/13879222_1235179076493734_1631898598554522774_n.jpg?oh=e6d74e7731f374be63a378e99ef3a88e&oe=58111449",
        "id": "1235179076493734"
     }
```

Here's my code so far

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/102060453138941?fields=photos{picture}&access_token=xxx', 
function(fbResults) {

        for(var i =0; i < fbResults; i++) {

            $('.gallery').append(

            '<img class="" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ this.id +'/picture" />'

            );


        }



    });
```

Comment: put a console.log(fbResults) right before the for loop and see what you get. the for loop is definitely wrong...it may be "i < fbResults.length", or "i < fbResults.data.length", depending on the json result. but you can easily find that out by doing some debugging.

Comment: btw, what access token are you using? hopefully not the same for every user? an app access token? you should not use that client side, it includes the app secret. also, you should not do this client side at all, or you may hit api limits. better do it server side (php curl, for example) and cache the results in your database.

Comment: I'm using an extended user access token, it's only one person that's going to be using it. I'm still learning php that's why I was doing it client side.

Comment: I added the consoleLog and it returned an array with 25 items but I'm not sure how to make each image show up. Right now i have an image tag with the src url set to src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ photos[id] + '/picture but nothing shows up.

Comment: the problem with jquery is that people don´t learn javascript anymore...you should learn that first, and only use jquery when you can really benefit from it - which is almost never ;)

Comment: i am pretty sure you don´t just get the array directly, but in a data object. check out my answer.

Comment: yea i definitely get what you mean about learning vanilla javascript first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fbResults.photos.data.length; i++) {
    $('.gallery').append(
        '<img class="" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ fbResults.photos.data[i].id +'/picture" />'
    );
}
```

Btw, you will only get 25 entries with the API. You can set a limit with the limit parameter or you can use paging: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

If you need to get all entries at once, i suggest using paging with a recursive function.

Btw, you would need to add the User Token to each line, which is a very bad idea. The whole code should better go to the server and you should actually download the photos and cache them. Just saying.

Comment: I tried your solution and I get this message in the console, Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: if that does not work, please include the exact output of console.log(fbResults) in your question.

Comment: so when I open the inspect tool the message I am getting is Object {photos: Object, id: "102060453138941"} then I get the error message Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: so i took the data part off of fbresults and the error message went away so now I can see Object {photos: Object, id: "102060453138941"} but still no images. my image src now is https://graph.facebook.com/'+ fbResults.data[i].id +'/picture"

Comment: you should use the chrome dev tools for debugging, you can see all objects in the console over there.

Comment: try console.log(fbResults.photos).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120742/discussion-between-travis-davis-and-luschn).